# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h2oaicore'

Tags: python, driverless-ai, h2o.ai

I am following the tutorial of driverless: Driverless AI Standalone Python Scoring Pipeline, you can check it in the following link:

http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/scoring-standalone-python.html#tar-method-py

I am performing:

**Running Python Scoring Process - Recommended**

but, when running the last step:

**DRIVERLESS_AI_LICENSE_KEY = "pastekey here" SCORING_PIPELINE_INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES = 0 /path/to/your/dai-env.sh ./run_example.sh**

the following error happens:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "example.py", line 7, in
>
> from scoring_h2oai_experiment_5fd7ff9c_b11a_11eb_b91f_0242ac110002 import Scorer   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scoring_h2oai_experiment_5fd7ff9c_b11a_11eb_b91f_0242ac110002/**init**.py",
> line 1, in
>
> ```
> from .scorer import Scorer   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scoring_h2oai_experiment_5fd7ff9c_b11a_11eb_b91f_0242ac110002/scorer.py",
> ```
>
> line 7, in
>
> ```
> from h2oaicore import application_context
> ```
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h2oaicore'

--
Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it doesn't find your h20aicore module. One brute force method to import it could be do the following in your python script:

```
import sys 
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("path/to/module"))
```

or alternatively you should add it to your python path.

Comment: Could you please describe where can I find ```h2oaicore``` in ```h2o``` module ????

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @BlackPhoenix's comment. It is looking for h2oaicore module. The DAI Python scoring pipeline comes with a h2oaicore .whl file. Check out the shell script, `run_example.sh`. It should contain steps about pip installing h2oaicore.

Comment: where is ```run_example.sh``` located?